# Topojson animating one flight

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have tried to animate a single flight based on two coordinate pairs (serving as starting point and landing point). However I got stuck with the error:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "...".

coming from d3.js.

I don't think d3 itself has an issue; it's more likely that it's my implementation. Here is my hunch for the actual culprit:

```
           var routeOne = svg.append('path')
              .datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [coordinatesSH,coordinatesTK]})
              .attr('class', 'route')
              .attr('d', path);
```

Full code at my [block](https://bl.ocks.org/AbnormalDistribution-2020/8fe94852cbf22fa4eda865c29f555874).

To my best inspection and trouble shooting, everything seems to be in order. I even hard-coded the coordinate data for simplicity. I'm not sure why it's a no go.

**Question** 
What is causing the error, and how can I animate the plane to go simply from one point to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datum has projected coordinates. Instead of that, it should contain just the coordinates themselves:

```
.datum({type: "LineString", coordinates: [[121.4737,31.2304],[139.7690,35.3804]]})
```

Here is your code with that change: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/35411b29afd3b69f5310f395109b09e2/caeb523aef9dd377a9d3ba624e32b9f3d93d1ccf